# Send info from One browser to another in Laravel 5.2.37

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have a page where user can Add/Update records. Code is written in Laravel 5.2

Let's say I opened the that add/update page in chrome and same url in FireFox. So, if user create a new record in Chrome browser, info should be received immediately to Firefox. So, that I don't need to send ajax based reqeust to server to show complete list.

My question is, where should I start for this? Is there any blog that I can go through step by step ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You definitely need to use WebSockets to achieve it. There a couple of good links in the tiagoRL's answer. But also, since you said you are using Laravel 5.2 I strongly recommend you to broadcast events. If you are a Laracasts user, take a look to the related videos.

Basically this is the main link:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/events#broadcasting-events

Also to simplify the server-side stuff, I'd go for [Pusher](http://www.pusher.com)

Comment: Do you have any code snippet for the better understanding?

Comment: Hi, sorry I don't have an snippet for that, quite difficult to do it since this a client/server approach that requires some services in place. However I recommend you to watch this 4-episodes series in Laracasts https://laracasts.com/series/real-time-laravel-with-socket-io (sign up there it is just 9$/month) and watch it. You will really understand how it works, with examples, clear explanations and step-by-step process. Jeffrey explains there how to do it using you own server side websockets + Laravel 'redis' driver for broadcasting. Once you master that, go for Pusher if you want.

Comment: If you NEED to use Websockets depends on how much "traffic" there is. Its the most 'perfect' way to solve the problem. But maybe simple ajax calls are already solving the issue... depending on the load/realtime behaviour.

Comment: I meant NEED to do it in the right way. Ajax is not an option to imitate this behavior. You can do a setinterval + Ajax call to emulate real time however get ready to get a request flooding in your web server. Not scalable at all

Answer (score 3):

To have this kind of realtime messaging between two or more clients you'll need to use sockets. One option is to use AJAX pooling, but if you want to be real time, then use sockets.

With sockets you can create connection tunnels between many clients, however you will still need a server implementation. Due the this nature of persistent connections, you'll need a server architecture that can support many connections open at the same time, that's why NodeJS non-blocking IO comes in hand, using less resources than PHP would, for example. 
More about this can be found here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

On the client side, there are **websockets**, which is a feature implemented in **HTML5 compliant browsers**.

References:

- Here is a tutorial: https://blog.kaazing.com/2012/08/08/a-step-by-step-tutorial-of-building-a-simple-peer-to-peer-websocket-app-part-1/
- One server implementation is available for NodeJS called Socket.IO http://socket.io/
- The video here shows exactly what can be done with it: http://tutorial.kaazing.com/
- Another good reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Answer (score 3):

This is a very normal thing to do and is achieved via AJAX background polling. You can do

#### Assumption

- If user must be authenticated to see the page, in both browsers the same user is logged in.
- Demand is low, so server load will be minimal.

  - If this is not true, look into web sockets.

#### Structure

- Route for page (that you already have)
- Route to return rows

  - all rows
  - rows starting from certain point

So the page loads and retrieves all rows, either server side or client side. Set the last row ID as a JavaScript variable. Then set an AJAX call to a timer. The AJAX call sends the last row already on the page, if there are new rows they are returned and the last row variable is updated. Alternatively you can use timestamps to track which rows are new.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of sharing session or cookies across different browsers.
Your problem is also unrelated to the programming language / framework in which your project is written. 
The way I recommend you is to make periodical ajax calls to fetch newly added rows only in order to prepend or append them to the current list.

This way, you save lots of resources and time not refreshing the whole list.
Although I have never used it, if you prefer a persistent connection than socket I/O is the way you should follow.

You can check the following page for more info on ajax or socket I/O comparison.
http://www.cubrid.org/blog/cubrid-appstools/nodejs-speed-dilemma-ajax-or-socket-io/

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You can start with this:

[Step by Step Guide to Installing Socket.io and Broadcasting Events with Laravel 5.1 using Laravel Homestead](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/step-by-step-guide-to-installing-socketio-and-broadcasting-events-with-laravel-51)

This example shows you how use real time events.

The idea in your case is to send an event when a new record is saved or updated, and when the others receives this event, refresh the list of records.